# Trouble using orbeon-auth

Tags: orbeon

I'm trying to set up authentication using the orbeon-auth servlet ising orbeon 4.7-CE and am having a bit of trouble getting to an auth dialogue box. It's been a long time since I've used orbeon and I'm a bit rusty on a few things. The last time I used the Resin servlet container whereas this time I'm using tomcat6 which is a bit new to me.

The intention is to replace the orbeon-auth servlet with a JRADIUS baed one that'll auth users against our RADIUS service.

When I try to run my app, all I get is an "Unauthorized page" appearing. It looks as if its failing when trying to use orbeon-auth. I've highlighted the bit I think is wrong in the logs.

I've set up a virtual host in tomcat6 and am calling https://xforms.york.ac.uk/orbeon/console-reg/ below are the appropriate config bits and log outputs. If someone could point me in the right direction I'd be grateful.

Rgds
Alex

Config and logs:-

```
<Host name="xforms.york.ac.uk" appBase ="xformapps"
        unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

 <Context path="/orbeon" docBase="orbeon" reloadable="false" override="true" crossContext="true">
           <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator"
                               changeSessionIdOnAuthentication="false"/>
           <Parameter override="false" 
              name="oxf.resources.priority.0" 
              value="org.orbeon.oxf.resources.FilesystemResourceManagerFactory"/>
           <Parameter override="false" 
              name="oxf.resources.priority.0.oxf.resources.filesystem.sandbox-directory" 
              value="/usr/share/tomcat6/orbeon/resources"/>

           <Resource name="jdbc/freeradius" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              initialSize="3" maxActive="10" maxIdle="20" maxWait="30000"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              poolPreparedStatements="true"
              validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
              testOnBorrow="true"
              username="xxxxx password="yyyy" 
              useInformationSchema="true"
              url="jdbc:mysql://a.b.c.d:3306/freeradius?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true"/>
       </Context>
       <Context path="/orbeon-auth" docBase="orbeon-auth" reloadable="false" override="false" crossContext="true">
       </Context>
```

Then in the orbeon properties-local.xml I've got

```
   <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.http.ssl.hostname-verifier" value="allow-all"/>
    <property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.url-rewriting.service.base-uri" value="http://xforms.york.ac.uk/orbeon"/>
    <property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.persistence.exist.uri" value="http://xforms.york.ac.uk/orbeon/fr/service/exist"/>
    <property as="xs:anyURI" name="oxf.fr.persistence.exist.exist-uri" value="htts://xforms.york.ac.uk/orbeon/exist/rest/db/orbeon/fr"/>
    <property as="xs:anyURI" processor-name="oxf:page-flow" name="authorizer" value="/orbeon-auth"/>
    <property as="xs:string" processor-name="oxf:page-flow" name="page-public-methods" value="HEAD"/>
```

In the orbeon-auth/web.xml I've got 
.....
    
        
            Console Reg
            /console-reg/
        
        
            *orbeon-service
        
    
    
        
            Everything else
            /*
        
        
        
    
    
        BASIC
    
    
        orbeon-service

What I see in Catalina.out is

```
15-Oct-2014 16:22:44 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke FINE: Security checking request GET /orbeon/console-reg/
15-Oct-2014 16:22:44 org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase findSecurityConstraints FINE:   No applicable constraints defined
15-Oct-2014 16:22:44 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke FINE:  Not subject to any constraint
15-Oct-2014 16:22:46 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke FINE: Security checking request GET /orbeon-auth/console-reg/
15-Oct-2014 16:22:46 org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase findSecurityConstraints FINE:   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Console Reg]' against GET /console-reg/ --> true
15-Oct-2014 16:22:46 org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase findSecurityConstraints FINE:   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Everything else]' against GET /console-reg/ --> true
15-Oct-2014 16:22:46 org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase findSecurityConstraints FINE:   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Console Reg]' against GET /console-reg/ --> true
15-Oct-2014 16:22:46 org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase findSecurityConstraints FINE:   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[Everything else]' against GET /console-reg/ --> true
15-Oct-2014 16:22:46 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke FINE:  Calling hasUserDataPermission()
15-Oct-2014 16:22:46 org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase hasUserDataPermission FINE:   User data constraint has no restrictions
**15-Oct-2014 16:22:46 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke FINE:  Calling authenticate()
 15-Oct-2014 16:22:46 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke FINE:  Failed authenticate() test**
15-Oct-2014 16:22:46 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke FINE: Security checking request GET /orbeon/fr/style/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
```

What I see in orbeon.log is

```
2014-10-15 16:29:58,184 INFO  ProcessorService  - /console-reg/ - Received request
2014-10-15 16:30:00,317 INFO  PageFlowControllerProcessor  - unauthorized {controller: "oxf:/app /console-reg/page-flow.xml", method: "GET", path: "/console-reg/", status-code: "403"}
2014-10-15 16:30:00,324 INFO  PageFlowControllerProcessor  - unauthorized {controller: "oxf:/page-flow.xml", method: "GET", path: "/console-reg/", status-code: "403"}
```

Comment: However, if I actually call https://xforms.york.ac.uk/orbeon-auth/console-reg/ then I do get an auth prompt. I can successfully authenticate and the tomcat6 does come back with a successful auth

Comment: So things seem to be going wrong when I call xforms.york.ac.uk/orbeon/console-reg/, logs show 16-Oct-2014 10:11:15 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
FINE:  Calling authenticate()
16-Oct-2014 10:11:15 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase invoke
FINE:  Failed authenticate() test